# Is there any git web gateway which crossreferences Python source code

Tags: python, git, ctags, lxr, cgit

We are using cgit and Trac to browse our source from web browsers. One thing I'm missing is crossreferencing (i.e. links in the source code to the token definition). I've seen lxr, but it doesn't seem to plug into cgit or anything else.

Have you found anything of the sort?

Cheers,

Álex

Answer (score 2):

[Try OpenGrok](http://opengrok.github.io/OpenGrok/)

It supports Git and Python.

Comment: looks good. I've tried LibreOffice's install and Python crossrefs do not look good, but it's definitely an improvement...